# Blender closes when minimised or UI elements are closed

Tags: customization, windows

I’m having a bug which was not present about a week ago.

Every time I click the blender Icon in the Windows 10 taskbar to minimise it, it just completely shuts down. If I open a window within the blender UI, like the preferences window, and then close it, the whole program closes too. I have tried the following:

A fresh install of blender 2.79, 2.78, and the daily build of 2.80.

Setting blender back to factory settings.

Turning my PC off and on again.

Updating NVIDIA graphics drivers.

Running Blender in compatibility mode.

Running the exe file direct from it’s location.

Running blender from the command prompt.

Running blender as admin (which my user profile already is)

None of these worked.
I have not noticed this problem with any software other than blender and it is a huge problem that makes it nearly unusable. Does anyone know what I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: Other working versions would indicate a possible problem with the OS. I have never observed this behavior with any of the versions on multiple PCs ruining multiple windows versions including multiple versions of Windows 10. I would check antivirus software or also is there any other software meant for UI customization installed on your PC? Are there any fancy unusual input or any other devices that come with any unusual software?

Comment: Blender closes if the console window is opened with Window->Toggle System Console and then is closed. That is normal behavior. It should be toggled from the Window menu.

Comment: Okay, I toggled the console window, but even if I click the blender window after that the whole thing still shuts down. I checked my antivirus too and found no issues.

Comment: There is only one situation, where Blender closes if you close one of it's independent windows - that is if it's the System Console Window. You did say that User Preferences window closes as well so that is not it, it seems it's irrelevant, sorry, just ignore it.

Comment: Did you say there were Windows updates? I think that might be it. They are famous for messing things up...

Comment: I've already installed them, so I'm not sure if I can do anything about that.

Comment: Seems like a bug in Windows. Maybe wait for another update or try to look into how to make sure all the updates were successful. I think I am running up to date Windows now, they seem to work fine. Maybe some update failed somehow. I think reinstalling the OS would fix it as well. Obviously I understand how that recommendation would sound... I honestly hope it doesn't come to that for you.

Comment: I'm going to check they installed correctly then report back. I have a very poor internet signal so I wouldn't be surprised if it got cut short.

Comment: Windows update troubleshooter did not bring up any issues or missed updates, and neither did my antivirus.

Comment: I just reverted to the last version of Windows and the problem is still there.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas besides clean install for the OS...

Comment: Same problem here, years later. I start up Blender 2.79b and if I click on the taskbar icon the application immediately shuts down. It also happens if I minimize the window from the top-right minimize button then click on the taskbar icon. It also happens if I minimize the window and then alt-tab the window back open.

This seems to come and go for me. Sometimes I gotta restart the application many times and it'll mysteriously stop doing this after a while. Then later it'll start doing it again.